# windows API to access partitions on an SD card

Tags: c, winapi, sd-card, disk-partitioning, fat32

Let's say I have an SD card with about 10 partitions on it, some of them ext4 and some of them FAT32. Windows (10) only shows and mounts the first FAT32 partition on the card in the file explorer. If I want to write a tool in C/C++ that mounts the other FAT32 partitions on the card:

1. can I do this from user space without needing a special kernel driver?
2. what windows API would I use for this and specifically what are the relevant functions I should look at, which let me access the drive as a raw device, and which lets me query the drive for partitions and mount them?

Comment: You can use `DeviceIoControl` (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adioltean/2005/05/04/how-to-query-the-list-of-diskspartitions-for-a-certain-volume-and-viceversa/) or **WMI** windows managed instrumentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394515(v=vs.85).aspx). Some samples are available. For pure C access you must take care of COM interfaces for WMI. Anyway using the MS non standard C compiler it will work with not so much efforts.

Comment: windows mount partition auto, when you open it by name. you can create temporary mount by `DefineDosDevice` or permanent by `IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_CREATE_POINT`

Comment: Still the best way would be to write some KMD with Ntddk and have greater control over the resource management, instead of relying on the slow high level APIs

Comment: (but you will have to use IRQLs to avoid race conditions shortly speaking)

Comment: @Edenia - kernel mode here nothing give. *IRQLs* ?!

Comment: @RbMm the interrupt request level

Comment: @Edenia - no, i good know what is `IRQL` - i dont understand how you want use IRQL for this task and avoid race conditions

Comment: no any IRQL here need at all